# Submitting webform without refreshing the page

Tags: 7, blocks, webforms

I have a webform displayed as a block:

[image]

Is it possible to submit the form without refreshing the page, followed by a message saying the webform has successfully been submitted? If so, could someone guide me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out [Webform AJAX](https://drupal.org/project/webform_ajax) module.

> This module adds AJAX support to Webform (3.0 and above).
>
> As a first step it focusses to simply add form AJAX paging and submit. Form submissions get ajaxified including prev/next pages. Especially for multipage forms, this leads to faster loading (less data transfer), better usability and finally smaller server load.

I think that may do what you are asking. Should then show up as options in form settings.

[image: Form Settings]

Also, be sure you are set to "no redirect"

[image: redirect screenshot]

Comment: The ajax response uses the horendous drupal_set_message. Seriously, it's ugly.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option on the block configuration page to "Show all webform pages in block", that will do what you what you need.

See, attachment:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! However I want the webform to be replaced by the confirmation message, now the page just reloads and I get an empty webform again.